# Issue managing the cache in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sencha-touch, browser-cache

We are having a great problem with the cache in our hybrid app, this issue in IE11 is very critical.

For example of the current "bug", we manage the new version of the app, saving in localstorage the version number, in IE this variable is not overwrite because the cache saves the previous number or with others features is cached and doesn´t appear correctly.

Do you any tip or solution for this purpose and manages correctly this issue with the browser´s cache?